# Is this how you handle errors in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, exception

I'm learning programming in JS and preparing for future interviews. I'm currently trying to figure out how to do proper error handling (I suppose this will come up during interview questions whatever is the exercise).

If my task was to implement a simple function for character lookup and you were an interviewer, would you consider the below code appropriate? What should I change? Is this really how it works in the real world that you write this code for every function that you create?

I know that for this functionality you could use simpler ways such as indexOf() or includes(). This is just an example.

```
function isCharacterInString(character, string) {

    // error handling code checking for invalid inputs

    if (typeof character === undefined || typeof string === undefined) {
        throw new TypeError('Mandatory inputs are missing. Please provide 2 inputs: a character and a string.');
    } else if (typeof character !== 'string') {
        throw new TypeError(`First input "${character}" is not a string. Inputs to this function must be a string.`);
    } else if (typeof string !== 'string') {
        throw new TypeError(`Second input "${string}" is not a string. Inputs to this function must be a string.`);
    } else if (character.length > 1 || character === '') {
        throw new TypeError(`First input to this function must be a single character. "${character}" is not a single character.`);
    }

    // loop & check for character in string

    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (character === string[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "*you write this code for every function that you create?*" - no, absolutely not. You only put such input argument validation on functions where you don't trust the caller to pass the right values, such as exported functions of your library or the boundaries between your application and other systems.

Comment: @Bergi what if your code is thousands of lines long? when something fails would this not help when debugging any issue with the code? or are there so many other tools available that writing this does not add any value?

Comment: Yes, (if you consider TypeScript as a tool), TypeScript would make 3 of those 4 checks superfluous.